# change the location in header doesn't work

Tags: php

i try to change the page with header function but for some reason it doesnt work, i echoed the ob_start() result and it showed 1. there is not much of a code but here it is:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
header('Location: http://www.google.com');

?>
```

it simply shows 1

one more thing, here is the ob_status output with vardump

```
array(5) { ["level"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(1) ["status"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(22) "default output handler" ["del"]=> bool(true) }
```

suggestions?

EDIT: at first there was an echo call before the start_ob()

Comment: `echo ob_start();` huh?

Comment: Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Why do you `echo ob_start()`? Moreover, you can't change header after any content is sent.

Comment: simply to test, its not always like that on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started output before `header()`. It showed 1 (`true` in fact) and supressed effect of `header()` function. Remove `echo` from there.

From [***php.net***](http://php.net/header):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

As a side note:

1. Try to remove all blank lines before and after  section markers. It might be a reason.
2. Try to place header() call before ANY output.

Comment: Try to remove all blank lines before and after `<?php ... ?>` section markers. It might be a reason.

Comment: @Anton.P try to place `header()` call before ANY output.

Comment: it was the blank lines man. thank you very much, please add it as edit to post so people that will look at the accepted answer will know what it was about

Answer (score 1):

You make an `echo` before sending headers. You can't do that. Headers can't be changed after any content is sent.

This `echo` shows `1` because `on_start()` function returns boolean value `true` or `false`.

You say, that even if you remove this line, it still doesn't work. Aren't you sending any content earlier? Even a space? Do you have enabled errors displaying? Including notices.

Comment: yes, i did it to test the ob_start status. its not always like that and it still doesnt work.